# About the decomposable vector space

Tags: representation-theory

[image]

I want to ask you whether the direct sum mentioned in the definition is unique, or the vector space $V$ could be written as a direct sum of another two $G$-invariant subspaces? 
I ask about the existence and unique cases. thanks!

Comment: @LeonMeier $W\le V$ is $G$-invariant if $gW\subseteq W$ for all $g\in G$.

Comment: @Leon Yes. Decomposability depends on $G$ and how it acts on the vector space. I mentioned the trivial action on $\Bbb R^2$ and decomposing as a pair of lines in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be many ways to decompose a representation into nonzero invariant subspaces. One may use an analogy with arithmetic: in general, composite numbers can be written as the product of two numbers (neither equal to $1$) in many different ways. For instance, $24$ may be written as any of the products $2\times 12$, $3\times 8$, $4\times 6$. In general, however, we can *refine* the decomposition of $V$, for instance if $V=V_1\oplus W$ is an internal direct sum and $W=V_2\oplus V_3$ is an internal direct sum, then $V=V_1\oplus W=V_1\oplus V_2\oplus V_3$ is an internal direct sum.

We may proceed in this way to continue refining a decomposition until we can't anymore; then we have a decomposition of $V$ into a direct sum of *indecomposable* subspaces. In general, even if a representation is indecomposable, it may still have subrepresentations, it's just that those subreps have no *complementary* reps as part of a decomposition. However, for complex representations of finite groups, indecomposability and irreducibility are equivalent.

The decomposition into indecomposables/irreps (meaning, the set of subspaces used in the internal direct sum) is generally not unique. For instance, suppose $G$ acts trivially on the two-dimensional real vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$. The irreps are precisely the one-dimensional subspaces, so decomposing $\mathbb{R}^2$ into an internal direct sum of irreps is equivalent to picking any pair of distinct lines - but there are *many* pairs of distinct lines to use!

However, the multiset (set with repeated elements allowed) of *isomorphism classes* of ireps used in the decomposition into irreps *is* uniquely determined. Moreover, there given any isomorphism class $(\ast)$ of irreducible representation of $G$, there is a unique subrep $W\le V$ with the following properties: all irreducible subreps of $W$ are isomorphic to $(\ast)$, and all subreps of $V$ isomorphic to $(\ast)$ are contained in $W$. In other words, the subspace $W$ which sums *all* of the irreducible subreps of a certain type is uniquely determined. It is called an *isotypical component*.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessarily unique. If
$$V_1 = V_3 \oplus V_4$$
with $V_3$ and $V_4$ being non-zero invariant subspaces of $V_1$, then both $V_3$ and $V_4 \oplus V_2$ are non-zero invariant subspaces of $V$ and additionally,
$$V = V_3 \oplus (V_4 \oplus V_2)$$